# How would I make sure that the needed headers required in my C++ program are installed on the user's machine?

Tags: c++, dependencies, header-files

I have a C++ project that uses the popular **Boost** library. The problem is, if someone downloads my code off say, Github and tries to build it, it won't work unless they have Boost installed, which could be an inconvenience. I'm just wondering how I would go about making sure these headers are accessible for the user so they can build the app themselves.
Would I have to copy them into a separate folder in the directory? Are there better solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: By stating in your Readme.md file that boost is required.

Comment: *which could be an inconvenience* -- State up front they need an installation of `boost` and any other dependencies before compiling your application.  Just like an application says "you need operating system <x> or above, <y> amount of memory, etc.",

Comment: You need to be careful about including source code of a third party lib in your own packages/code. There often legal limitations depending on the license of the third party project... In some cases you may be able to add the third party lib as git subdirectory... This won't be sufficient for all boost components though and there are a TON of build options boost allows for.

Comment: *which could be an inconvenience.* -- Building an app from C++ source isn't something a novice would do. Someone willing to compile a C++ application is assumed to be knowledgeable enough to understand that source code may have external dependencies.  So it shouldn't be an "inconvenience" -- they will either have boost, install it if they don't have it, or skip your code, knowing full well they can't use boost.

Comment: I'm not going to build your project because it is an inconvenience, period.  My most convenient method would be to down load an executable that is compatible with my platform.  There are many servers containing different executables depending on your platform.  Also, there is always a chance that when I build your project, I'm going to have errors; this takes time.  I can usually avoid the frustration by downloading an executable.

Comment: FYI, C++17 and later have [`__has_include()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) available. Your source code can use that to check if Boost headers are available and if not then fail the compile with `#error` telling the user to install Boost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite **a lot** of options on how to manage dependencies. In my experience many platforms define it's own conventional way of doing so. E.g. in iOS development people either use CocoaPods or SwiftPackages (and sometimes Carthage). For Android applications, developers usually define dependencies in `dependencies` block of their Gradle-build script (which essentially takes them from remote repos).

There isn't necessary an industry standard, but there is something other developer usually find *consistent*.

As far as I'm concerned, in C++ world the dependencies are expected to be managed via `CMake`. I wouldn't say that CMake itself defines conventional way of managing dependencies (there is far more than one approach of doing so), but the part which everyone expects is that when your CMake script finishes successfully, it has all dependencies set up. Here are a few options you have when managing dependencies via CMake:

- **`find_package`** - the most widespread way. As a result, this command should end up with include dirs and a library target configured in your cmake script (against which you link your own project). I'm not a big fan of this command to be honest, because it really depends on how the host machine is configured, and you are supposed to write additional `Find<Library_name>.cmake` files where you give instructions for CMake how to find the given library.
- **Add your dependencies as git submodules in subdirectories of your project and use `add_subdirectory` on those dependencies in you `CMakeLists.txt`** - my preferable way. First, I like it because it's highly portable, you don't expect the host machine to be configured in any specific way, second, it doesn't spread dependencies beyond the project directory. Last, but not least, the submodules keep state of the repository used, so everyone who clone your code will get exactly the same version of the dependency you use and at the same time they have a possibility to update it (pull more recent version as needed).
- **Package managers (e.g. [Conan](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan))** - you have already guessed, I think, that dependency management in C++ is not very novice-friendly and there are still some new options being developed to address this issue. [Conan](https://conan.io/) is one of such options, and it's compatible with CMake (but it's not very widespread yet).

Thanks to flexibility of CMake, you also can add any intermediate steps to ease the installation of dependencies, including, but not limited to automatic git submodules pull and update, or installing some missing tools.

Comment: Just adding to your answer in that Bazel has a nice solution for this too with `http_archive`